# What disease is this (tomato plants)?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, tomatoes

I got these seedlings that i re-potted. The bigger leaves get white/yellow spots and the baby leaves go dark as they sprout and wilt very fast. I have a few varieties in small containers that seem to be all affected

What is it? Can anything be done? Are these beyond repair?

[image: example 1]
[image: ex 2]
[image]

EDIT:
I have coriander nearby with similar symptoms, mini leaves wilting and spots on the older ones
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not convinced its TMV (see answer below) but what are these plants growing in in terms of soil, do the pots have drainage, and what's all the white covering over the top of the pots? Are the growing indoors or outside, or in a greenhouse? Where are you in the world?

Comment: @Bamboo Standard potting soil, I added NPK granules on top. They are growing outside, I am situated in Malta. The white is newspaper I just added after they started developing these problems because I read to minimize exposure of the soil. I have coriander that have similar symptoms, see my original post edited with photos

Answer (score 3):

tomato shows some browning at margins, that *looks* like water stress...

the coriander looks like it has a bacteria or fungus from over watering or just staying wet in the foliage...  then the second picture, looks like water stress again.

I do not think they are similar conditions.

Neither one of these plants like water to be sitting on their above ground parts, if you adjust watering to just the soil and the condition doesn't get worse, you probably don't need to do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

This TMV tomato mosaic virus. There’s nothing you can do.
All plants should be burnt and compost sent to your recycling facilities for incineration

Comment: Thank you. My coriander has similar symptoms. Does it corroborate? Cf photos added in original post.

Answer (score 0):

Looks viral to me, probably Tomato yellow leaf curl virus
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato_yellow_leaf_curl_virus

Not your fault mate, there's a tiny moth that had infected your plants, and there's very little you can do about it once the plant was infected